# Linux sockets: Segmentation error

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets

Linux n00b here. So about a month ago I installed emacs and the gcc/g++ compiler and have gotten started with programming. I found some code online for an echo server program, copied it and compiled it to test the networking functions. It compiled but then when I tried to run it I got the error message: **Segmentation fault(core dumped)**. When I looked carefully at the debugger details it was an error in the "fwrite()" function. I linked the code to the library *libstdc++.a* upon compiling and creating the output file so it does make me wonder if there is some critical error in the actual library functions and I need to go back, find the function .c sourcecode, and then add them to the headers to make it work. The code is posted below. Anybody else had this problem?

```
#include <sys-socket.h>       /*  socket definitions        */
#include <sys-types.h>        /*  socket types              */
#include <netinet-in.h>        /*  inet (3) functions         */
#include <unistd.h>           /*  misc. UNIX functions      */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <ether.h>
#include <string.h>


/*  Global constants  */

#define ECHO_PORT          2002
#define MAX_LINE           1000
#define LISTENQ            5


ssize_t Readline(int sockd, char *vptr,size_t maxlen) {
    ssize_t n, rc;
    char*    c;
    msghdr* buffer;

    buffer->msg_iov->iov_base = vptr;
    buffer->msg_iov->iov_len  = maxlen;

    for ( n = 1; n < maxlen; n++ ) {

      if ( (rc = recvmsg(sockd,buffer, 1)) == 1 ) {
    c = buffer->msg_iov->iov_base++;
        if (*c == '\n' )
        break;
    }
    else if ( rc == 0 ) {
        if ( n == 1 )
        return 0;
        else
        break;
    }
    else {
        if (rc < 0 )
        continue;
        return -1;
    }
    }

    buffer->msg_iov->iov_base = 0;
    return n;
}


/*  Write a line to a socket  */

ssize_t Writeline(int sockd, char *vptr) {
     msghdr     *buffer;


     buffer->msg_iov->iov_base = vptr;
     size_t      nleft = buffer->msg_iov->iov_len;
     ssize_t     nwritten;

    while ( nleft > 0 ) {
    if ( (nwritten = sendmsg(sockd, buffer, nleft)) < 0 ) {
          return -1;
    }
    nleft  -= nwritten;
    buffer += nwritten;
    }

    return nwritten;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int       list_s;                /*  listening socket          */
    int       conn_s;                /*  connection socket         */
    short int port;                  /*  port number               */
    struct    sockaddr_in servaddr;  /*  socket address structure  */
    char     *endptr;                /*  for strtol()              */
    char      buffer[MAX_LINE];




    port = 5000;


    /*  Create the listening socket  */

    if ( (list_s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0 ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ECHOSERV: Error creating listening socket.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    /*  Set all bytes in socket address structure to
        zero, and fill in the relevant data members   */

    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port        = htons(port);


    /*  Bind our socket addresss to the 
    listening socket, and call listen()  */

    if ( bind(list_s, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) < 0 ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ECHOSERV: Error calling bind()\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ( listen(list_s, LISTENQ) < 0 ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ECHOSERV: Error calling listen()\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    /*  Enter an infinite loop to respond
        to client requests and echo input  */

    while ( 1 ) {

    /*  Wait for a connection, then accept() it  */

    if ( (conn_s = accept(list_s, NULL, NULL) ) < 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ECHOSERV: Error calling accept()\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    /*  Retrieve an input line from the connected socket
        then simply write it back to the same socket.     */

    Readline(conn_s, buffer, MAX_LINE-1);
    Writeline(conn_s, buffer);


    /*  Close the connected socket  */

    if ( shutdown(conn_s,0) < 0 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ECHOSERV: Error calling close()\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: Here's some further details from the debugger:  *Segfault happened at 0x7f6302d53c04<fwrite+52>: mov (%rcx),%eax PC(0x7f6302d53c04) OK  source "(%rcx)" not located in a known VMA region(needed readable region!) destination "%eax" ok*  So this looks like an operand size conflict but where is the fwrite() function implemented?? I did not write this code mind you.

Comment: @bennofs: It said "no stacktrace available" so unfortunately I cannot. The function "fwrite()" is in the <stdio.h> header as a prototype. So that is what appears to be the problem. But I have no idear how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

```
ssize_t Writeline(int sockd, char *vptr) {
     msghdr     *buffer;


     buffer->msg_iov->iov_base = vptr;
```

your pointer buffer is not initialized. You might look at this code snippet to do it correctly:

```
      /* This structure contains parameter information for sendmsg.   */
   struct msghdr mh;

      /* The message header contains parameters for sendmsg.    */
   mh.msg_name = (caddr_t) &dest;
   mh.msg_namelen = sizeof(dest);
   mh.msg_iov = iov;
   mh.msg_iovlen = 3;
   mh.msg_accrights = NULL;            /* irrelevant to AF_INET */
   mh.msg_accrightslen = 0;            /* irrelevant to AF_INET */

   rc = sendmsg(s, &mh, 0);            /* no flags used         */
   if (rc == -1) {
      perror("sendmsg failed");
      return -1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

[sendmsg](http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/sasc/doc750/html/lr2/zsendmsg.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the `buffer` pointer variables in your `Writeline()` and `ReadLine()` functions.

```
ssize_t Writeline(int sockd, char *vptr) {
     msghdr     *buffer;

     //this is not appropriate as buffer does not point to appropriate memory.
     buffer->msg_iov->iov_base = vptr;

     size_t      nleft = buffer->msg_iov->iov_len;
     ssize_t     nwritten;
     ...    
    return nwritten;
}
```

Accessing `buffer->msg_iov->iov_base` or `buffer->msg_iov->iov_len` or even `buffer` is not appropriate without allocating it or setting to appropriate memory is not valid.

Comment: So I reinstalled linux(along with emacs, gcc++, and the libraries)and it WORKS!!! I knew there was a bigger problem than just the source code. A lot of my other headers weren't working properly so perhaps the previous reinstallation(after trying to tweak the network settings caused a boot error)mustve corrupted those files.

Answer (score 1):

Did you actually COPY this, or did you copy bits and then paste it together yourself?

It's not very hard to fix at least to the point where it doesn't crash by itself - I didn't get further because my firewall settings are too strict to just fire up a program and use a random port, and I don't feel like messing up my firewall setting just to test your code.

So, as pointed out `msghdr *buffer;` means that the pointer for `buffer` is uninitialized. The easy fix is to NOT use a pointer, and instead use the address of `buffer` when you need it. You then need to have an `iov` data structure.

So, in receive, you end up with something like this:

```
msghdr   buffer;
iovec    iov;

buffer.msg_iov = &iov;
...
if ( (rc = recvmsg(sockd, &buffer, 1)) == 1 ) {
    c = vptr++;
    buffer.msg_iov->iov_base = vptr;
```

Note the `&` in front of buffer. I also changed the next line, as it was doing `++` on a `void` pointer, which is not clearly defined in C++, so the compiler gave a warning. (There's also a warning for `buffer` not initialized).

A similar treatment is needed in the `WriteLine function.

```
iovec    iov;

buffer.msg_iov = &iov;
buffer.msg_iov->iov_base = vptr;
size_t      nleft = MAX_LINE;

... 
   if ( (nwritten = sendmsg(sockd, &buffer, nleft)) < 0 ) {
   ....

   nleft  -= nwritten;
   vptr += nwritten;
   buffer.msg_iov->iov_base = vptr;
```

Again, the increment of `iov_base` is incrementing a `void *`, which hasn't been defined since I wrote it above, so need to make sure that the pointer has a different type - reusing `vptr` is decent here.

As an aside, I changed the `nleft` to set to `MAX_LINE`, as you don't pass in the size of the line. I would suggest that you change it so that it does take the size as an argument, similar to the `ReadLine` function.

Finally, please do yourself a favour and use `-Wall -Werror` when compiling the code - that means that you will get warnings when you do "silly" things - it may work, but it may also NOT work. Nearly all warnings from the compiler are USEFUL.

Remember when using a pointer in C or C++, you should make sure it points at something. Just writing `T* ptr;` only gives you a pointer, there is no memory attached to the pointer, so before you USE that pointer, you should assign it in some way.

I'm far from convinced this covers everything - but it should get you somewhat on the way to getting something working.

Comment: Matt, I copied-n-pasted it.

Comment: I would find somewhere else to copy'n'paste from... If this is exactly how it came, then it's pretty rubbish, I'd say.

Comment: Alright, I made the requested changes and it still crashed..............AGAIN! The error report mentions the file **libc.so.6** not being installed properly. And the shit hit the fan when I attempted to relocate it to a different directory. So clearly the problem is the library file and not the actual source code. But that's for the tips.

Comment: Really? Sounds unlikely - it may be that the changes above aren't sufficient - as I said, I never actually CONNECTED to the server, so it's entirely possible that it does crash somewhere else.

Comment: To check that your libc is correctly installed, try writing a simple application with "Hello World" in it, and see if that works.

Comment: And here's some code that definitely works: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/clientserver.html